# Calculating the addition of $2$ hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: binary, hex, sign

I'm missing some intuition on signing convention for hexadecimal numbers. Assume the following are all signed numbers:

Let R1 = CFD45432 and R2 = 6DEE8765.  Then, what is R8 = R2 - R1 and what are its CNZV flags?

The way I went about doing this question is to first see that R1 can be written as -4FD45432, then just carry out the subtraction normally.  This gives me an answer of R8 = BDC2DB97... I have no idea how to analyze this and determine what the flags are.  Could someone help me understand?

PS: I'm not sure how to write Latex on StackOverflow.  I've used stack exchange again but the "$" signs aren't working for Overflow.

Thank you!